# How to writing the buildspec yaml code in cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I making the codebuild with cdk

It can accept the buildspec as yaml, however ,how can I do the same thing in cdk?

What I want to do is like this, of course it doesn't work though,

I forcely put the yaml code in commands.

```js
    const buildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'project', {
      environment: {// I guess I need to select ubuntu and image 4.0},
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
          build: {
            commands:['
              version: 0.2
                phases:
                    install:
                        runtime-versions:
                            docker: 18
                    build:
                        commands:
                            - apt-get install jq -y
                            - ContainerName="tnkDjangoContainer"
                            - ImageURI=$(cat imageDetail.json | jq -r '.ImageURI')
                            - printf '[{"name":"CONTAINER_NAME","imageUri":"IMAGE_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
                            - sed -i -e "s|CONTAINER_NAME|$ContainerName|g" imagedefinitions.json
                            - sed -i -e "s|IMAGE_URI|$ImageURI|g" imagedefinitions.json
                            - cat imagedefinitions.json

                artifacts:
                    files:
                        - imagedefinitions.json
              
              ',         
            ],
          },
        }
      })
    });
```

And also I guess I need to choose the image to do the buildspec such as `Ubuntu`

Where can I set these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDK does not expose a method to inline a YAML buildspec at synth-time. You could do this yourself by parsing existing YAML into a JS object and passing the result to `BuildSpec.fromObject`.

CDK's `codebuild.Project` gives you several other ways to provide a `buildSpec`:

- `BuildSpec.fromObject` inlines a buildspec from key-value pairs at synth-time.  It should follow the [CodeBuild buildspec format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-example).  CDK will output a stringified JSON buildspec in the CloudFormation template.  If you want CDK to output YAML instead, use `fromObjectToYaml`.  Both methods take key-value pairs (type: `[key: string]: any;`) as input, so TS can't offer much typechecking help.
- `BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename` tells CodeBuild to use a buildspec file  *in your source*  at run-time.  The filename is passed in the CloudFormation template.

Here's an example of parsing a YAML string into inlined YAML output, using the [yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) package.  Note that the environment is defined outside the buildspec:

```js
import * as yaml from 'yaml';

const fromYaml = yaml.parse(`
  version: '0.2'
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
`);

new codebuild.Project(this, 'YamlInYamlOutProject', {
  environment: {
    buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0, // Ubuntu Standard 5
  },
  buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObjectToYaml(fromYaml),
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I set `buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename("./buildspec.yml")` and set file in cdk root_directory but error comes. `[Container] 2022/03/09 14:09:08 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src509486276/src
[Container] 2022/03/09 14:09:10 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/03/09 14:09:10 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/src509486276/src/buildspec.yml: no such file or directory` I s there anythin I need to do?

Comment: @whitebear CodeBuild can't find your file.  Check the path.  CodeBuild runs from the project root.  See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage).

Comment: Where is the project root ? I tried both `cdk root directory` and containers  root directory (such as `/usr/src/app`), but in vain. How `/codebuild/output/src509486276/src/` is made??

Comment: @whitebear CodeBuild executions start with `pwd` set to the root of your source (i.e. your repo code).  If your buildspec is in the repo's `cdk` directory, then `./cdk/buildspec.yml`.

Comment: THank you for your help. I set the buildspec.yml in my container `/usr/src/app/buildspec.yml` However it still can't find `Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /usr/src/app/buildspec.yml: no such file or directory`.  where is the repo's directory?

Comment: @whitebear Build projects are usually associated with a source (e.g. Github repo), which is specified via the [source property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html#source).  If your project has no source you must inline the buildspec.

Comment: mmmm I see I use `ECR` as source  there is only image and no raw source code,no place to put buildspec...  That's the reason maybe..

Comment: It must be the another problem to solve, but your explanation so much helps to progress. Thanks for very much.

Comment: @whitebear _"no raw source code,no place to put buildspec... That's the reason maybe"_  Yes, exactly.  Your best option is to inline the buildspec with `BuildSpec.fromObject`.  Good luck!