# CDK: Codebuild project not able to find buidspec.yml file

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I am trying to load `plan-buildspec.yml` file in my codebuild Project, however its not able to find my builspec.yml no matter whichever path I give.

I did refer to this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7329, but not luck

```
YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/srcXXXXXXX/buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml: no such file or directory
```

here is my CodeBuild pipeline definition

```
 const TFplan = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'tf-plan', {
      projectName: 'tf-cicd-plan',
      description: 'Plan stage for terraform',
      environment: {
        computeType: ComputeType.SMALL,
        buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_4
      },
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('../buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml')
    })



const TFplanbBuildAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: 'Build',
      project: TFplan,
      input: sourceOutput,
    });
```

my tree structure, buildspec files are present in buildspec directory.

```
.
├── README.md
├── bin
├── buildspec
├── cdk.json
├── cdk.out
├── jest.config.js
├── lib
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── test
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml`

The path is relative to the [project root](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7329#issuecomment-614738439).

---

Note: When you use `fromSourceFilename`, CodeBuild looks for your buildspec file only at runtime. It expects a file in the pipeline artefact (= *from a file in the source* = your repo).  The template the CDK creates has the file name only:

```json
"Type": "AWS::CodeBuild::Project",
"Properties": {
    "Source": {
        "BuildSpec": "buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml",
```

If instead you want the CDK to embed the buildspec itself with the pipeline definition, you must use [Buildspec.fromObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.html#static-fromwbrobjectvalue), passing key-value pairs.  CDK puts the buildspec in the template at synth-time:

```json
"Type": "AWS::CodeBuild::Project",
"Properties": {
    "Source": {
        "BuildSpec": "{\n  \"version\": \"0.2\",\n  \"phases\": {\n    \"build\": {\n   ...",
```

Comment: Its is the same error, it didn't solve!

Comment: @JatinMehrotra  Double-check the buildspec file exists in your repo `origin` in the target branch.

Comment: I am deploying it form my local system, so I can confirm you my buidspec file do exists inside buildspec directoy

Comment: @JatinMehrotra  When you use `fromSourceFilename`, CodeBuild looks for your buildspec file at runtime in the pipeline artifact \*from a file in the source\* (= origin = your remote repo, = from GitHub or wherever).  If you want CDK to embed the buildspec with the pipeline definition, you must use [Buildspec.fromObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.html#static-fromwbrobjectvalue).

Comment: but the GitHub issue users are using file which exist in local system not in the runtime? is that correct?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I can't tell you about that user's experience.  I can only repeat that `fromSourceFilename` does not look in your local file system.   [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71408103/1103511) shows how to inline a YAML buildspec file into the pipeline definition at synth-time from your local files.

Answer (score 0):

as @fedonev mentioned, when fromSourcefilename is trying to find the file only at runtime not at the synth time.

I fixed it with this

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as yaml from 'yaml';

const TFplan = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'tf-plan', {
      projectName: 'tf-cicd-plan',
      description: 'Plan stage for terraform',
      environment: {
        computeType: ComputeType.SMALL,
        buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_4
      },
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml', 'utf8')))
      //buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('buildspec/plan-buildspec.yml')
    })

    const TFplanbBuildAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: 'Build',
      project: TFplan,
      input: sourceOutput,
    });
```

**Update:**

There is also a much simpler way:

To use: fromAsset uploads the yaml file to S3 b bucket created by cdk bootstrap and referenced from the codebuild project.

```
 buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromAsset("codebuild-buildspec/apply.yml"),
```